# Is there a julian date function in APEX,

Tags: apex-code

Is there a julian date function in APEX,

For example today [May 28 2013] has the julian date 2456442

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
public static Integer getJulianDate(integer I,integer J,integer K){   

   //  I= YEAR
   // J= MONTH
   //  K= DAY

  return ( K-32075+1461*(I+4800+(J-14)/12)/4+367*(J-2-(J-14)/12*12) /12-3*((I+4900+(J-14)/12)/100)/4 );
  }
```